# Time-Delayed MySQL "Update" for More Realistic Tally of Online Video Views

Tags: mysql, counting, timedelay

I'm creating a video embed page for a real estate site, where a user can go to watch a video tour of a given home.  There is no other reason to visit that particular page, so I figured that I could use a simple MySQL Update to a "video view tally" column for that homes's row, which will update views=views+1 each time the page is loaded.

That's easy enough, but I want to give as realistic a "view" count as possible, so I'm trying to come up with a way to have that view tallied ONLY once the page has been loaded for a set number of seconds (say, 30).

Any thoughts on a good way to handle the timing aspect?  I'd like to avoid javascript, if possible, but I'm open to if it it's handled simply enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the only way you will ever know if the page is still active is to have a client-side technology (like JavaScript) tell you that it is.

You can add a "counter" page that isn't meant to be viewed directly, but instead is accessed via JavaScript after a 30 second page timer has expired.  The act of JavaScript accessing that page will trigger the counter logic.

Comment: Regarding the "counter" page:  So I would set up the MySQL update on <em>that</em> page instead, and that page load is what would actually trigger the update... I think I've got it.

Just to be clear, though... the user won't see any disruption through this process, correct?  (You'll have to excuse my lack of JS experience)

Comment: Yes, that should do it.  FYI, the trick is borrowed from something spammers used to do: They would define an "image" in an HTML email but the image source would point back to a counter page.  The counter page was passed your email address.  If that "image" was loaded, the counter page recorded the email address passed back to it as a valid address.  That's why modern email clients block images from unknown senders.